# Miscrosoft Access Table and data inputting issues

Tags: ms-access

I am having a few issues with Access (I'm not a total novice, but I'm miles away from expert).

I've not used Access in a while and have decided to build a database for my upholstery business.

I made a customers table so that every time I entered a new customers details on a form, it stores the data in the customers table.

I then made  a quotations form where I scrolled through the records until it pulled up the relevant customers details.

and here is where the problem lies...

I then want access to take the details from the boxes containing the customers info and also the details from the quotation and store it in a table so that I then have a table called quotations with all customers details and the quotation details so that I can print the reports (quotes).

I'm at a loss as how to tie the whole thing together and make it work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause "non-normalization" and is taught in DB 101.  Non-normalization bad.  Very bad.

What you want to do is create a field in your Customers table called CustomerID.  This field should be an AutoNumber field, and should also be your Primary Key.

In your Quotations table, create a field called QuotationsID.  This should also be AutoNumber/Primary Key.  In this table, you will store the CustomerID in a field, and **only** the CustomerID relating to the customer.  This way, you can change any information in the Customers table without having it impact the rest of your dataset.

You will then join these tables in a **query**.  You should **never** store this in a separate table, as your data will become disjointed as soon as your customer changes his phone number or any other information.  You can set up a query like this:

```
SELECT CInfo.*, Quot.*
FROM tblCustomers CInfo
LEFT JOIN tblQuotations Quot
ON tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblQuotations.CustomerID
```

This should give you every quotation relating to each customer.  You can then filter based on CustomerID if you only want to see data relating to a specific customer by adding a WHERE clause to the query above:

```
SELECT CInfo.*, Quot.*
FROM tblCustomers CInfo
LEFT JOIN tblQuotations Quot
ON tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblQuotations.CustomerID
WHERE CInfo.CustomerID = "12345"
```

Comment: When i run the first query it says "Syntax error in join operation" and highlights tblCustomers

Comment: Is that the name of your customers table?

Comment: the table is called Customers yes

Comment: If the table is called Customers, then change the code I posted to reflect that.  tblCustomers has to be changed to Customers.  It's not going to work "out of the box", you need to make changes to table and field names to reflect what you have.